# zend mail smtp options

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, zend-mail

I am trying to send email by smtp options using zend/Mail

Here is my code:

```
//use the base class
use Zend\Mail;  
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;  
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
```

and here is is my mail functionality code in controller

```
//mail functionality
        $email = "xxxx@gmail.com";
        $pas = "xxxx";

        // setup SMTP options  
        $options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(array(  
                    'name' => 'localhost',  
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
                    'port'=> 587,  
                    'connection_class' => 'login',  
                    'connection_config' => array(  
                        'username' => $email,  
                        'password' => $pas,  
                        'ssl'=> 'tls',  
                    ),  
        ));  

        $this->renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');  
        $content = $this->renderer->render('patient-register/email/template', null);  

        // make a header as html  
        $html = new MimePart($content);  
        $html->type = "text/html";  
        $body = new MimeMessage();  
        $body->setParts(array($html,));  

        // instance mail   
        $mail = new Mail\Message();  
        $mail->setBody($body); // will generate our code html from template.phtml  
        $mail->setFrom('xxxx@xxxx.com','mub');  
        $mail->setTo('xxxx@gmail.com');  
        $mail->setSubject('TESTING THE EMAIL ACCCOUNT');  

        $transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);  
        $transport->send($mail);
```

So when i try to send mail from my localhost, its get sucess

But when i try to send the email from the remote server, 128.199.123.145 and the server is a centos server from digitalocean.

Is that anything to change in remote server.

Thanks,

Comment: Firewall issues?  Make sure port 587 is open on egress from your remote server.

Comment: can i use any other port, instead of 587

Comment: Have you checked the php/webserver error logs? Have you configured SMTP on the server?